# Passing object as parameter on button click

Tags: android

I've just started to learn Android, and I have a quick question. I have a separate class Team, and within it there's 3 variables (String name, int goals, int points). In my main activity I want to increment the goals and/or points for each Team object once a button is clicked. At the moment I have a method:

```
        public void updatePoints(View v, Team t){
        t.points++;
        }
```

and in my xml file I have:

```
android:onClick="updatePoints"
```

which relates to a Button. Can I pass a Team object like above? If so, how can it be done?
As I said I'm only starting to learn Android so any advice would be a appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have....

```
android:onClick="updatePoints" // in XML file
```

then in your java file you need to define...

```
public void updatePoints(View v){   
    // This is where you update each team

    // I think v.getId() retrieves the id of the button (or view) that was clicked
}
```

I assume in your activity you have...

Team team[]; // an array of teams (more than one), so you need to do something to identify the team your trying to update... so I'd change your definition of Team

```
public class Team {
    public int identity; // This is the new field
    public String name;
    public int goals;
    public int points;
}
```

Although you can, I wouldn't use the tag property to identify a team... I'd use the identity field to identify individual teams. That way a team isn't linked/tied to a button... more versatile IMHO

Answer (score 2):

the signature for the method used as the **onClick** listener defined in XML must be

```
public void myMethod(View v)
```

otherwise it won't be found.

Then, you can do whatever you want inside this method, for example to invoke `updatePoints()`.
If you want to maintain the relationship between the Team and the View, you can use [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29).

For example:

```
button.setTag("com.example.team", myTeam);
```

and then in the onClick method

```
public void myMethod(View v) {
   ((Team)v.getTag("com.example.team")).points++;
}
```

Comment: That's the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare Team as a variable in your class:

```
private Team myTeam;
```

Then, create your method:

```
public void updatePoints(View v){
        myTeam.points++;
}
```

using class variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create event listener for that buton in order to do something when clicked , then you need to create an object of that Team class , and then you just call updatePoints method inside that class.